# what is undefined index error?

Tags: php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd">
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST">
<?php
//create connection
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', "root", "");
if(isset($_POST["add"])){
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$std =$dbh->prepare("insert into new2 (username,password) values(?,?)");
$std->bindParam(1,$username);
$std->bindParam(2,$password);
$std->execute();
}
?>
username: <br />
<input type="text" name="useraname" />
<p>
password: <br />
<input type="text" name="password" />enter code here
<input type="submit" name="add" value="Add" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This results in the following error:

```
 Undefined index: username in C:\wamp\www\bist\addtonew2.php on line 11
```

What is the reason of this type of error? I am just trying to insert some data into the `new2` table.

Comment: means that these variables are not set (i.e user not filled them)

Comment: @Akam: No. It means it's the first time you load the page and the form has not been submitted yet.

Comment: @Jon `if(isset($_POST["add"])){` ...

Comment: @Musa: Right, I missed that. The "no" still stands though.

Comment: @Jon: Well it is true that the user didn't fill in the `username` field. They filled in the `useraname` field.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in you input name attribute

```
<input type="text" name="useraname" />
```

should be

```
<input type="text" name="username" />
```

For avoiding inserting empty username and password you can use:

```
if(isset($_POST["add"]) && isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
//your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An undefined index notice is emitted if you try to access an element of an array that does not exist. For example:

```
$my_array = array(
    "name" => "Joe",
    "age" => 30
);
echo $my_array["languages"];  // notice emitted; "languages" does not exist
```

In your case, you're accessing it on `$_POST` rather than on an array you created, but the same reason applies. In your case, it's because you misspelled `username` as `useraname` in the HTML, so trying to access the value of `username` won't work.

Comment: thnx guys.....problem was on 20th line i typed username as useraname...

Comment: can anyone suggest me a good ebook for beginners on php??

Comment: Go to Youtube, you will find great tutorials there.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access to username `$username = $_POST["username"]`, but you do not have one, take a look at

```
<input type="text" name="useraname" />
```

you have a typo. That is why **username is undefined**.